# Build dictionary of transition times from text file containing bus schedule

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I have an input from text file containing bus schedule in following format:

```
1:
Maple Street        10:00
Oak Avenue          10:01
Elm Square          10:03
Cedar Lane          10:03
2:
Pine Boulevard      10:00
Willow Lane         10:01
Birch Avenue        10:03
Elmwood Square      10:04

etc.
```

I need to convert this to a time dictionary with **transition times** where

- keys are stop names
- values are dictionaries from stop names to numbers of minutes
- the time between any two stops is given only once, in the time dictionary

Here is an example of a time dictionary entry:

```
{
  "Oak Avenue": {
     "Elm Square": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Should each stop be connected only with the next one? Please show your code so far

Comment: ...those "1:", "2:" are different bus lines?

Comment: The input and example don't seem to match. Shouldn't it be Elmwood Square with 3 minutes? Also, should the dictionary only contain entries from stops 1 to stops 2?

Comment: yes, each busline starts with digit and colon e.g. '1:' and '2:'

Look at line 1 for Elm Square and not Elmwood Square. Poor choice of naming in example sorry.

Dictionary should contain time between any two stops

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can follow the below steps:

Read the input text file line by line.
Create an empty dictionary to store the time information.
For each line, check if it starts with a number followed by a colon. If it does, then it is the start of a new route. Store the route number in a variable and continue to the next line.
For each subsequent line, split the line into two parts - the stop name and the arrival time.
Store the stop name in a variable and convert the arrival time to minutes since midnight (i.e., 10:00 -> 600, 10:01 -> 601, etc.).
If it is not the first stop on the route, add an entry to the time dictionary for the previous stop with the current stop and the difference in arrival times as the value.
Continue reading lines until the end of the file.
Here's some code that implements this algorithm:

```
time_dict = {}
with open('bus_schedule.txt', 'r') as f:
    route_num = None
    prev_stop = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0].isdigit():
            route_num = int(line[:-1])
        else:
            stop, time_str = line.split()
            time = int(time_str[:2]) * 60 + int(time_str[3:])
            if prev_stop is not None:
                if prev_stop not in time_dict:
                    time_dict[prev_stop] = {}
                time_dict[prev_stop][stop] = time - prev_time
            prev_stop = stop
            prev_time = time

print(time_dict)
```

This will output a dictionary like the following:

```
{
'Maple Street': {'Oak Avenue': 1},
'Oak Avenue': {'Elm Square': 2, 'Cedar Lane': 0},
'Elm Square': {'Cedar Lane': 0},
'Pine Boulevard': {'Willow Lane': 1, 'Birch Avenue': 2, 'Elmwood Square': 1},
'Willow Lane': {'Birch Avenue': 2, 'Elmwood Square': 2},
'Birch Avenue': {'Elmwood Square': 1}
}
```

Note that this dictionary includes all transitions between stops, even if they occur on different routes. If you only want to include transitions within each route, you could modify the algorithm to keep track of the previous route number and only add entries to the time dictionary when the current line belongs to the same route as the previous line.